# Microsoft Visual Studio SQL server connection - invalid pointer

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

[image]

So, I want to create a SQL database in Microsoft SQL Management Studio and connect it to Microsoft Visual Studio. I linked the database to Visual Studio and it worked. Now, I want to open that connection to test it with a button on a windows form application. Every time I try, it says "invalid pointer" but the database name is correct. I don't know what is wrong.

I still get the invalid pointer error...My instance name is DESKTOP-BJSAO6B but it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: While using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(); You must provide the connection string and not only the Database Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need provide a proper connection string like

```
string connectionString =
        "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=student;integrated security=True;";


    using (SqlConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 connection.Open();
 MessageBox.Show("You are connected");
 }
```

where SQLEXPRESS - name your MSSQL instance ( may be different). More you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408266/how-to-form-the-connection-string-for-a-sql-server-express-instance)

Answer (score 1):

For Ex:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=Server-Name; Initial Catalog= Database-Name;Integrated Security=True"; //If you are using a local Database.

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
MessageBox.Show("You are connected");
```